# Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.3.2 missing Azure Mobile App Template

Tags: azure, xamarin, mobile, visual-studio-2017, azure-mobile-services

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3.2 to write Xamarin mobile apps.

My issue is that File->New->Project does not offer Azure Mobile Apps anymore.  I have attempted to find the templates online and run repair on my Visual Studio installation, but the project template is no where to be found.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could choose Cloud->ASP.NET Web Application template and you will find that Azure Mobile App is a sub project template of ASP.NET Web Application.

[image]

Comment: I did not assume that was the template given its new location and icon, but all of the features seem to be there.  Thanks!